# JavaScript string search for array of objects

Tags: javascript

- I need to implement a search function for a table.
- I got an array of objects with **unnecessary** object properties.
- I need to map the array to get **necessary** properties and then do the filtration.

This is my code.

```js
const items = [
  {
    name: 'pathum',
    id: 1,
    status: true,
    createdAt: 'KKKK',
    country: {
      name: 'SL',
      code: 12,
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'kasun',
    id: 1,
    status: true,
    createdAt: 'KKKK',
    country: {
      name: 'USA',
      code: 23,
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'hansi',
    id: 1,
    status: true,
    createdAt: 'KKKK',
    country: {
      name: 'GERMANY',
      code: 34,
    },
  },
];

const tableColumns = ['name', 'country.name'];

const onSearch = (e) => {
  e = e.toLowerCase();

  const mappedItems = items.map((item) => {
    Object.keys(item).forEach((key) => {
      if (!tableColumns.includes(key)) delete item[key];
    });
    return item;
  });

  if (e) {
    const result = mappedItems.filter((item) => {
      const str = JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase();

      if (str.search(e) >= 0) return item;
    });
    return result;
  } else {
    return mappedItems;
  }
};

console.log(onSearch('GERMANY'));
```

In an item object, I only need to get these two fields

```
const tableColumns = ['name', 'country.name'];
```

But this only gives me the name property

```
const mappedItems = items.map((item) => {
    Object.keys(item).forEach((key) => {
      if (!tableColumns.includes(key)) delete item[key];
    });
    return item;
  });
```

**My first question is how to map to expect a result like this**

```
  {
    name: 'pathum',
    country: {
      name: 'SL',
    },
  },
```

Second question is `JSON.stringtfy` map whole object. So If I search "name" it will return all the objects becasue "name" is there in the all records in the stringtify string.

How do I avoid keys in the object when doing the stringify?

Hope my question is clear to you all.

How do I modify this code to get that expected functionality?

Comment: Do you want to search in all properties or only in `tableColumns` properties? Eg: If you search `"KKKK"`, do you want to return all the objects since they all have `createdAt` but it is not included in `tableColumns`

Comment: @adiga I do only search `tableColumns`

Comment: Are you trying to modify the original items array or trying to create a new array without modifying the original?

Answer (score 0):

```
const tableColumns = ['name', 'country'];
const deleteProp = ['code'];

const mappedItems = items.map((item) => {
Object.keys(item).forEach((key) => {
console.log(key);
  if (!tableColumns.includes(key)) delete item[key];
  if(key == 'country') delete item[key][deleteProp[0]];
});
return item;
});
```

This may answer your first question.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the object has any of the `tableColumns` paths which includes the searched text. And then get a subset of the filtered objects and only include the `tableColumns` properties

```js
const items=[{name:"pathum",id:1,status:true,createdAt:"KKKK",country:{name:"SL",code:12,},},{name:"kasun",id:1,status:true,createdAt:"KKKK",country:{name:"USA",code:23,},},{name:"hansi",id:1,status:true,createdAt:"KKKK",country:{name:"GERMANY",code:34}}],
    tableColumns = ['name', 'country.name'];

function onSearch(array, e) {
  const output = [];
  for (const o of array) {
    const hasProp = tableColumns.some(path => getProperty(o, path).includes(e))
    if (hasProp)
      output.push(subSet(o, tableColumns))
  }
  return output
}

function getProperty(o, path) {
  return path.split('.').reduce((acc, p) => acc?.[p], o) || ''
}

function subSet(o, paths) {
  const output = {}

  for (const path of paths) {
    let keys = path.split('.'),
        last = keys.pop(),
        value = o;

    const final = keys.reduce((acc, k) => {
      value = value?.[k]
      return acc[k] ||= {}
    }, output);

    final[last] = value?.[last];
  }

  return output;
}

console.log(onSearch(items, 'pat'));
console.log(onSearch(items, 'kasun'));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't change data. You can clone the data and change it.
And, search should be search. Don't put the data formation in it.

Let's start.

```js
const items = [
    {
      name: 'pathum',
      id: 1,
      status: true,
      createdAt: 'KKKK',
      country: {
        name: 'SL',
        code: 12,
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'kasun',
      id: 1,
      status: true,
      createdAt: 'KKKK',
      country: {
        name: 'USA',
        code: 23,
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'hansi',
      id: 1,
      status: true,
      createdAt: 'KKKK',
      country: {
        name: 'GERMANY',
        code: 34,
      },
    },
];
// We will use object to get the fields you want. To reuse, you can add more fields you want.
const tableColumns = {
//  id: 1, 
    name: 1,
    country: {
        name: 1
    }
}

// getting the mapped items
const mappedItems = items.map((item) => {
    const temp = {};
    Object.keys(item).forEach((key) => {
        const target = tableColumns[key];
        if (target) {
            if (typeof target === 'number'){
                temp[key] = item[key];
            } else {
                temp[key] = {};
                Object.keys(target).forEach(subKey => temp[key][subKey] = item[key][subKey]);
            }
        }
        
    });
    return temp;
});
// search function, use local varibles
const onSearch = (array, countryName) => {
    return array.find(element => element.country.name.toLowerCase() === countryName.toLowerCase())
}

const searchResult = onSearch(mappedItems, 'germany');
console.log(searchResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new array using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const items = [{
    name: 'pathum',
    id: 1,
    status: true,
    createdAt: 'KKKK',
    country: {
      name: 'SL',
      code: 12,
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'kasun',
    id: 1,
    status: true,
    createdAt: 'KKKK',
    country: {
      name: 'USA',
      code: 23,
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'hansi',
    id: 1,
    status: true,
    createdAt: 'KKKK',
    country: {
      name: 'GERMANY',
      code: 34,
    },
  },
];
let minItems = items.map(function(item) {
  return {
    "name": item.name,
    "country": {
      "name": item.country.name
    }
  }
});
console.log(minItems);
```